# MySql SELECT/DELETE won't work on a certain column

Tags: php, mysql, select, sql-delete

I'm using PHP. When I use SELECT on a certain column, it returns an error but all other columns work fine. I checked and there are no NULL/blank etc. cells.

Here's the code:

```
    $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE from='$user' AND reply='-1'");
```

DELETE won't work either on that same column, but all other columns work!
as far as I can tell there's nothing different about the column and I've tryed it on different scripts aswell. All other collumns on the table work perfectly fine except for this one. Is this a bug?

(Basically I made it so that every row has a "from" and "to" cell. If the message is a reply to another then the "reply" value changes to that message's ID.)

Comment: You didn't post your error message. You didn't specify which column is causing the problem (though I have a guess). Try fixing your question and maybe you'll get an answer.

Comment: What's the mysql error code? Shot in the dark your mysql user doesn't have suitable permissions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the column `from` needs backticks (``` `` ```) around it or you need to rename it.  MySQL thinks you are saying `FROM` twice.

Comment: Actually `~` is a tilde, you're thinking of a backquote.

Comment: Doh! Edited to reflect my lapse in thinking.

Comment: Yep that worked. Does this mean I don't actually have to put "FROM" in caps?

Comment: Nope, you can do all lowercase.